Is this limit resolution legit?
I have to calculate
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(\dfrac{2x-5}{2x-2}\right)^{4x^2}$$
After having arranged it as
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(1 - \dfrac{3}{2x-2}\right)^{4x^2}$$
I used $2x-2 = t$ thence
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} \left(1 - \dfrac{3}{t}\right)^{(t+2)^2}$$
Is now legit to solve it like this?
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} \left(\underbrace{\left(1-\dfrac{3}{t}\right)^t}_{e^{-3}}\right)^t\cdot \lim_{t\to +\infty}\underbrace{\left(1-\dfrac{3}{t}\right)^{4t}}_{e^{-12}}\cdot \lim_{t\to +\infty}\underbrace{\left(1-\dfrac{3}{t}\right)^4}_{1}$$
Hence the limit is zero.

Is this legit? Why not, if? I mean the separation into three products of limits.


The justification for the first limit is missing.  Otherwise it would be okay

Yes if all the separated limits exist.

@BrianMoehring Yes I went a bit fast. It's zero because it's $e^{-3t}$ which goes to zero as $x \to +\infty$. That was my principal concern, actually, the possibility to solve a limit "inside a limit"

@J.N. The problem is that it's never actually $e^{-3t}$.  Rather, it's $(\alpha_t)^t$ where $\alpha_t \to e^{-3}$.  This means, for instance, that there's some $t_0$ such that $t \geq t_0$ implies $0 \leq \alpha_t \leq e^{-2}$, and therefore $0 \leq (\alpha_t)^t \leq e^{-2t}$.  Now, the fact that $e^{-2t} \to 0$ allows us to imply the original limit also tends to $0$.

A final note: The above argument is simple enough that I'd never require a professional to make it.  It's also close enough to a mistake students regularly make that, if you're still developing your intuition, you should go through these steps to explain to yourself why you can do this.

Yes indeed algebrically we have
$$\left(1 - \dfrac{3}{t}\right)^{(t+2)^2}=\left(1 - \dfrac{3}{t}\right)^{t^2}\left(1 - \dfrac{3}{t}\right)^{4t}\left(1 - \dfrac{3}{t}\right)^{4} \to 0\cdot e^{-12}\cdot 1=0$$
and product rule for limits holds.
As an alternative we can use that as $x \to 0$, $\log(1+x)\le x$ then
$$\log\left[\left(1 - \dfrac{3}{t}\right)^{(t+2)^2}\right]=(t+2)^2\log \left(1 - \dfrac{3}{t}\right)\le -\frac{3(t+2)^2}t \to -\infty$$

Note that $0\le 1-\frac 3t\le 1$
Therefore $0\le(1-\frac 3t)^\alpha\le 1$ for any power $\alpha>0$ and you can just ignore the $4t+4$ exponent with this rough inequality.
$$0\le(1-\tfrac 3t)^{(t+2)^2}\le(1-\tfrac 3t)^{t^2}\to 0$$

The three limits exist so yes. In general, $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)\cdot g(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) \cdot \lim_{t\to\infty} g(t)$ if both limits exist.
